# Simple lambda function I could not understand

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, auto

I am learning C++14 lambdas with const, and today my friend showed me the following. I could not understand it.

1. Is it a lambda function? The syntax does not matches what I see usually.
2. it syntax matches with a lambda function, but it fails with a long error.

```
int main()
{
    // 1.
    const auto x = [&]{
        auto l = 0;
        l = 99;
        return l;
    }();

    std::cout << x << endl;

    // 2.    
    const auto y = [&](){
        auto l = 0;
        l = 99;
        return l;
    };

    std::cout << y << endl;   

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know what 1 is, and why 2 fails to compile.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I wanted to know what is 1. and why 2. fails to compile.

(1)

```
const auto x = [&]{
        auto const_val = 0;
        const_val = 99;
        return const_val;
    }();
// ..^^  <--- execution
```

This is the definition *and* execution of a lambda that doesn't receive arguments (so the `()` part after `[&]` is optional and, in this case, omitted).

So `x` is an `int` (a `const int`) initialized with `99` (the value returned by the lambda)

As you can see, the name `const_val` for the integer variable inside the lambda is a fake, because the variable is intialized with `0` and then modified assigning to it the value `99`.

(2)

```
const auto y = [&](){
auto l = 0;
l = 99;
return l;
};
```

This is the definition only (no execution) of a lambda that receive no arguments.

So `y` is a variable (well, a constant) that contain the lambda and when you write

```
std::cout << y << endl;
```

you get an error because isn't defined the output for a lambda; you should try with

```
std::cout << y() << endl;
```

to execute the lambda and print the returned value (again `99`).